# Send SSH command when pressed to button

Tags: java, ssh

I have a small server running Ubuntu (12.04.1 LTS). I can control the server from putty but I want to do this with GUI. I know how to create Java applications with GUI. Anyway my question is, how to send ssh command when button clicked.

Comment: Any good reason not to use vnc?

Comment: I know vnc but I don't want to view whole desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) library allows you to do ssh programmatically from java.  This should allow you to send the necessary commands from you gui to your server.

Answer (score 0):

One more or less simple way to do this is to open a ssh tunnel and forward a port from your local machine to the server. I recommend using a key pair to omit entering a password. Next you write your application which could consist of two parts, your local GUI and some server which executes the commands on the server.
I still think that this a very complicated solution but the choice is yours.